# how to display map on pdf with wicked_pdf in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf for generating pdf in my rails application.

I need to display a map on pdf with iframe.

I used bellow code for the map.

```
%iframe{:frameborder => "0", :height => "200", :src => "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=#{spot_details.lat}, #{spot_details.lng}&hl=es;z=14&output=embed", :style => "border:0;width:100%;margin-bottom:20px"}
```

But it gives me simple frame without map like this http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/17/0515/h_1494853712_9065572_7571a033f7.png

Anyone, please suggest me how to display map on wicked_pdf with rails application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be working for me.

[Commit adding Google map in Iframe to wicked_pdf_issues project](https://github.com/unixmonkey/wicked_pdf_issues/commit/e60e2c6b384254e5b32e8d13f491118f17f38326)

[Resulting PDF - default style issue, but definitely working](https://wicked-pdf-issues.herokuapp.com/pages/issue_43980674.pdf)

Do you have other JavaScript or stylesheets that could be interfering?

It could be a timing issue if you have a slow connection from Google to your server.

Try increasing the default JavaScript rendering timeout with the option `javascript_delay` like this:

```
render pdf: 'mypdf',
  javascript_delay: 5000 # wait 5 seconds for JS to fully execute
```

Comment: I Added javascript_delay like bellow:

format.pdf { render :pdf => @trip_itinerary.trip.trip_name, :show_as_html=>false, :footer=>{:right => "#{Time.now}", :font_size => 8, :center => '[page]'},:size=>{:paperSize=>'A4'}, :margin=>{:top=>'0.8cm', :bottom=>'1cm', :left=>'1.5cm', :right=> "0.3cm"}, :javascript_delay=> 5000}

but getting an error like this:

Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: Unknown long argument --javascript-delay

Comment: @AmitBhanderi You must be using an older version of `wkhtmltopdf` that doesn't support `--javascript-delay`. Please update to a newer version.